# Find any of the field is updated or not in sql server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

If we receive an update statement that does not check if the value has changed in the where clause, what are the different ways to ignore that update inside a trigger?

I know we can do a comparison of each individual field (handling the ISNULL side as well), but where it's a table that has 50+ fields, is there a faster/easier way to do it?

Note:I want to save each and every event in logs for updated fields.for example i have 50 fields and one of the field is updated(for single row not for entire table),then i want to save only that updated field old value and new value in logs.

Thanks in Advance, RAHUL

Comment: Why would you want to ignore it? Would it not be fast to just apply the update?

Comment: By using trigger, you won't fetch an update query, but perform an operation on every single row that is to be updatet. 
Moreover, I don't think an update without checking if a value have changed (if only it has any WHERE clause so it doesn't update an entire table), will be much (if any!) slower than update that checks every single field.

Comment: I want to save each and every event in logs for updated fields.for example i have 50 fields and one of the field is updated,then i want to save only that updated field old value and new value in logs

Answer (score 0):

If this is more about logging changes to tables, a simpler solution may be to use Change Data Capture (CDC) tables.

Every time a change is made to a table, a row is written to your CDC table. Then you could write a query over the CDC table to bring you back just the data that has changed.

More information is on CDC tables is availble here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx